# How to link to items in an enum -can't cast Enumerator error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an enum and I want to have link that will show all the posts under that enum but I keep getting 'can't cast enumerator' what is the best way to do this or how can I fix the error please?

```
enum status: [:lost, :found]
```

link to view items in the enum

```
<li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Lost", items_path(status: "lost"), class: "nav-link" %></li>
<li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Found", items_path(status: "found"), class: "nav-link" %></li>
```

my controller looks like this

```
def index
    if params.has_key?(:status)
      @status = Item.statuses.find(params[:status])
      @items = Item.where(status: @status)
    else
      @items = Item.all
    end
  end
```

my view starts with this

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <%= content_tag :tr, id: dom_id(item), class: dom_class(item) do %>
    ...
```

Comment: Can you please add the error in your description? It is hard to try some solution without understood where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to keep it the way you have it then you need to access the enum appropriately as:

```
def index
    if params.has_key?(:status)
      @status = Item.statuses[params[:status]]
      @items = Item.where(status: @status)
    else
      @items = Item.all
    end
  end
```

This will return the Integer represented by the enum. However there are more direct methods such as

```
@items = Item.where(status: params[:status]) # Rails >= 5.0
```

Or even

```
@items = Items.public_send(params[:status]) # Rails >= 4.1 (when enum was introduced)
```

to use the scope created by using the `enum` method.

[See Here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) for more information.

Since [@mechnicov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10608621/mechnicov) convinced me the `Hash` pattern is better here is how I would migrate to this

- Change the enum in to `Item` `enum status: { lost: "lost", found: "found" }`
- Create a new migration to add a new column (`status2`)

```
def change  
  add_column :items, :status2, :string
end
```

- Create another new migration to migrate the data

```
def change 
 Item.reset_column_information
 [:lost,:found].each_with_index do |status,index|
   Item.where(status: index).update_all(status2: status)
 end 
 remove_column :items, :status
 rename_column :items, :status2, :status 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is this the best approach to handle something like this?

Comment: @albert honestly mechnicov has convinced me the Hash solution is better but that is not something you can just jump into you would need to alter your schema (twice) and create a migration pattern. So for what you are using right now I would say yes. To move to the Hash pattern you would need to create a new column (String) to hold the new values then you would need to map your current enums to the new Hash enums, drop the current status column and then rename the new column you created to status. I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the best way

I think the best way is using hash as enum and suffix (or prefix) like this:

```
enum status: { lost: "lost", found: "found" }, _suffix: true
```

In that case you need to hold `status` in your `items` table as string

What is the advantage of this?

It creates scopes: `Item.lost_status` and `Item.found_status`

Now you can use it this way:

```
<li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Lost", items_path(status: "lost"), class: "nav-link" %></li>
<li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Found", items_path(status: "found"), class: "nav-link" %></li>
```

And in controller:

```
def index
  @items =
    if params[:status].present?
      Item.send("#{params[:status]}_status")
    else
      Item.all
    end
end
```

Comment: What benefit does the `Hash` have over `enum status:  [:lost, :found]` which will map by index to an Integer value?

Comment: You are not bound to the array index. You can add new values and delete old ones later without worrying about their order. It's more scalable

Comment: Excellent reasoning. Deletion of an enum seems dangerous though without forethought for migrating old values.

Comment: I tried this now but I am not getting any item when I click on the lost or found link

Comment: @mechnicov I was so convinced I added a migration pattern to my answer. Please let me know if you disagree or see any flaw in the process